# Remove list element at index?

Tags: swift

There is a serious lack of methods available to lists in Swift. It is really disappointing, coming from a Python background. For example, I want to remove the first element, something like this would work in Python:

```
mylist = mylist[1:]
```

How do I remove an element from a list (preferably by index, but I can do whatever method is easiest)?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_176

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `removeAtIndex`

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]
arr.removeAtIndex(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a range of values, you can use `removeRange`:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x.removeRange(1...2) // result is [1, 4, 5]

var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x.removeRange(1..<2) // result is [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note that this method doesn't check for range bounds, so if you specify a range outside the array size, it will throw a runtime exception.